# Persisting new associated entity in preFlush handler (endless recursion)

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I've created a entity listener for a given entity `Foo`, which listens to the `preFlush` event. I want to create a new `Bar` entity whenever the `Foo` entity is updated or created.
My problem is the preFlush event is triggered again by the `computeChangeSets()` resulting in an endless loop. Anyone have a solution or an alternative method to approach this use case?

```
class SomeListener
{
    /**
     * @ORM\preFlush
     */
    public function onPreFlush(Foo $foo, PreFlushEventArgs $eventArgs)
    {
        $em = $eventArgs->getEntityManager();
        $uow = $em->getUnitOfWork();

        $bar = new Bar();
        $bar->setX('test');
        $foo->addBar($bar);

        $em->persist($bar);

        $meta = $em->getClassMetadata(get_class($foo));
        $uow->recomputeSingleEntityChangeSet($meta, $foo);
        $uow->computeChangeSets(); //This line invokes preFlush listener again
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `PreFlush` event is dispatched *before* the change-sets are computed.

In other words: Your calls to `recomputeSingleEntityChangeSet()` and `computeChangeSets()` are *not* needed here. Remove those and your listener should be working fine!

PS: `computeChangeSets()` will compute *all* change-sets, so you don't need to call `recomputeSingleEntityChangeSet()` along with it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm pretty sure I've tried that already, but my entity didn't persists to the database. The association is set to cascade persists. I'm not at work atm, tomorrow I'll try you suggestion.